# Problem with listing and matlab prettifier packages

Tags: matlab, latex

My Tex document start with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    left=2cm, % inner
    right=2cm, % outer
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    %showframe,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{MatlabCodeWithListing}
{\lstset{
    language=Matlab,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    keywordstyle=\color[RGB]{0,0,255},
    commentstyle=\color[RGB]{34,139,34},
    stringstyle=\color[RGB]{160,32,240},
    keepspaces,
    morecomment=[l][\color{blue}]{...},
    frameround=tttt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10!white},
    %rulecolor=\color{gray!20!white}
}}{}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\lstnewenvironment{MatlabCodeWithPrettifier}
{\lstset{
    language=Matlab,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    keywordstyle=\color[RGB]{0,0,255},
    commentstyle=\color[RGB]{34,139,34},
    stringstyle=\color[RGB]{160,32,240},
    keepspaces,
    morecomment=[l][\color{blue}]{...},
    frameround=tttt,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10!white},
    style=Matlab-editor,
    mlsectiontitlestyle=\bfseries\color{red},
    %rulecolor=\color{gray!20!white}
}}{}
```

With the `MatlabCodeWithListing` environment I have three problems:

1. No bold section title
2. No %{  %} comment
3. The box around the code is squared, but it has round corners, so the backgroundcolor overflows the round corners

So i read about `matlab-prettifier` and now:

1. The title section is not bold (but i could change the color)
2. The %{  %} comment is correct
3. The box around the code is as before
4. I have an extra hookright (and a white line) in the definition of the matrix A

The complete .tex file (after the introduction above) is:

```
\begin{document}

\chapter*{My errors}

\section*{What I use now}

With the \textit{MatlabCodeWithListing} I have:

\begin{MatlabCodeWithListing}
%% First section
h = L/N;
%{
    comment line
    comment line
%}
x = linspace(0,L,N+1);

%% Second section
L = 1;
N = 100;
A = [1 2 3; ...
     3 5 6];
% Solution
[x,uh] = upwind(L);
\end{MatlabCodeWithListing}

There are three problems: 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item No bold section title 
    \item No $\%\{\quad \%\}$ comment
    \item The box around the code is squared, but it has round corners, so the backgroundcolor overflows the round corners
\end{enumerate}

\section*{What I tried}

So i read about \textit{matlab-prettifier}:

\begin{MatlabCodeWithPrettifier}
%% First section
h = L/N;
%{
    comment line
    comment line
%}
A = [1 2 3; ...
     3 5 6];
\end{MatlabCodeWithPrettifier}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item The title section is not bold (but i could change the color)
    \item The $\%\{\quad \%\}$ comment is correct
    \item The box around the code is as before
    \item I have an extra hookright (and a white line) in the definition of the matrix $A$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I know that this post contains multiple questions, but could you try to understand me? Thanks a lot guys!